# Can someone explain this find method behaviour?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Recently I moved from C# to ruby on rails and checking records in rails console, in which i accidently made typo mistake. Instead of using `find() I used find{}`. It is working but it always returns first record from table. I don't know how this happened.

When i googled this I found out that it has something to do with block but i didn't get any idea.

```
I typed Book.find{3} instead of Book.find(3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when you pass a block to `find` it returns `super`:

```
def find(*ids) # :nodoc:
  # We don't have cache keys for this stuff yet
  return super unless ids.length == 1
  return super if block_given? ||
                  primary_key.nil? ...

  ...
end
```

Which then invokes `find` again, without a block and evaluating all other conditions as false:

```
return super unless ids.length == 1
return super if block_given? ||
                primary_key.nil? ||
                scope_attributes? ||
                columns_hash.key?(inheritance_column) && !base_class?
```

Allowing it to make a query to itself (the model, Book e.g) with a limit of 1:

```
...
statement = cached_find_by_statement(key) { |params|
  where(key => params.bind).limit(1)
}
...
```

Taking then the first element from the object statement, which is an ActiveRecord::StatementCache, similar to an ActiveRecord::Relationship object, holding 1 or more objects belonging to a model (Book in this case):

```
record = statement.execute([id], connection)&.first
```

Hence if `statements` is evaluated as truthy it is returned otherwise a RecordNotFound exception is raised:

```
record = statement.execute([id], connection)&.first
unless record
  raise RecordNotFound.new("Couldn't find #{name} with '#{key}'=#{id}", name, key, id)
end
record
```

You can see this [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L159:L182).